# How to pack a module without dependencies using Webpack for 'node' target?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have an isomorphic module that I want to release in a single file.

Building for web is trivial with webpack. However, for `target: 'node'` I would like to not include any dependencies in the output, as they're staying in the `package.json` and should be available with the standard `require`.

Is there a way to tell webpack to hook into requires only in the source directory, but leave other requires (such as `require('lodash')`) untouched?

A *workaround* I've found is to use `externals` and inject some `require`d modules to the output file:

```
// webpack.config

const externals =
  _(fs.readdirSync('node_modules'))
  .reject(s => /^\./.test(s))
  .keyBy().mapValues((v, k) => _.camelCase(v))
  .value()


module.exports = {
  ...
  externals,
  ...
}

// output file, assuming I'm injecting externals somehow:

Object.keys(externals).forEach(function (name) {
  try {
    global[externals[name]] = require(name)
  } catch (e) {
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

- Apparently externals can get a function and configuration options
  are richer
- https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals is exactly what I
  need